# HTML tag not working inside gmail

Tags: php, email

<strike>I send this link like this:</strike>

```
<p>Some Message here</p>
<a href="http://www.test.com">Visit Site</a>
```

but its showing like

```
<p>Some Message here
http://www.test.com</p>
```

Rather

```
  Some Message here
     Visit Site
```

do you know how to fix this issue?

EDITS

I use this code to send message.

When the message is like this

```
$msg ="
<p>Some Message here</p>
<a href='http://www.test.com'>Visit Site</a> 
";
```

Gmail shows or other email system

Some Message here

Visit Site

When the message is like this

```
    $msg ="
    <p>Some Message here
http://www.test.com
</p>

    ";
```

Gmail shows or other email system

Some Message here

http://www.test.com

Why does the first one not working as a link

code for sending message

```
$to = $user_email;
$subject = "My email"; 
$from = "email<noreply@test.com>"; 

$headers = "From: ".$from."\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";

$mail_content = "<html><body>"; 
$mail_content .= $msg;
$mail_content .= "</body></html>";
```

Comment: because `htt://` is not a valid protocol? it should be `http://`...

Comment: valid HTML for the win

Answer (score 0):

By reading your question i have another question, are you setting proper header before sending an email.

Because link  is html element, so setting up proper headers before sending an email should solve your problem.

Apart, if you still facing an then share your code of sending email.

May be this can help: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Thanks
Amit

Comment: he says other html works, so headers have to be correct

Comment: Also OP says `in gmail`... there's no programming question here.